# Get xmltype in field in Oracle column CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, xmltype

I have a column CLOB type that contain xml format.

I need to get with a simple query all different type from this field:

Ex. The field contain different types:

```
First record:
<Message type="New Address" xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/ecommerce/2009/01/scope/messages"><Customer ...

Second record:
<Message type="Added Email" xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/ecommerce/2009/01/scope/messages"><Customer ...

Third record:
<Message type="New Order" xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/ecommerce/2009/01/scope/messages"><Customer ...
```

I would like to retrieve:

```
New Address
Added Email
New Order
```

Comment: This can be useful: http://psoug.org/reference/xml_functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your data:

```
select xmlquery('/*/@type'
  passing xmltype(<clob column>)
  returning content)
from <your table>;
```

Demo:

```
create table t42 (clob_col clob);
insert into t42 values ('<Message type="New Address" xmlns="..."><Customer type="x"></Customer></Message>');
insert into t42 values ('<Message type="Added Email" xmlns="..."><Customer></Customer></Message>');
insert into t42 values ('<Message type="New Order" xmlns="..."><Customer></Customer></Message>');

select xmlquery('/*/@type'
  passing xmltype(t42.clob_col)
  returning content)
from t42;

XMLQUERY('/*/@TYPE'PASSINGXMLTYPE(T42.CLOB_COL)RETURNINGCONTENT)
----------------------------------------------------------------
New Address
Added Email
New Order
```

Or this:

```
select xmltype(<clob_column>).extract('/*/@type')
from <your table>;
```

Demo:

```
select xmltype(clob_col).extract('/*/@type')
from t42;

XMLTYPE(CLOB_COL).EXTRACT('/*/@TYPE')
-------------------------------------
New Address
Added Email
New Order
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm) about querying XML.